# Unobtrusive styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

According to [this article](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/11sp/lectures/slides/lecture14-unobtrusive-timers.shtml#slide14):

> well-written JavaScript code should contain as little CSS as possible

I wonder if I can use a `class` or a similar method in the following demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit Element Style</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <input type="text" id="input" value="#000000">
    <script>
        document.getElementById('input').oninput = function () {
            document.getElementById('div').style.background = this.value;
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mUBjc/)**</kbd>

Comment: Nope, not really, in your case whatever the user types in is set as the background, there's really no point of doing that with classes, nor is it really possible. Also note that it says "as little as possible", it doesn't say you should never apply styling with javascript.

Comment: @adeneo: _“nor is it really possible”_ – well of course it is _possible_, but as you said there’s little point in doing that here.

Comment: @CBroe - Anything is possible I guess, but that would mean having a class for every hex color, and for colors like `red`, `green` etc. not to mention that you now can type in things like `url(image.png)`, and replicating that with classes is .... wait for it ... not possible

Comment: @adeneo: _“but that would mean having a class for every […]”_ – of course _that_ is impossible … nah, I was more thinking in terms of [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule) to dynamically create/modify stylesheet rules.

Comment: @CBroe: I wonder why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mUBjc/2/) doesn't work.

Comment: Well, first of all because `div {background: this.value}` is not a valid rule – you have to use proper string concatenation here to insert the value. Second of all, because there are _two_ stylesheets embedded by jsfiddle already, and your div formatting is part of the second one, so if you add it to the first, your rule from the second one still takes precedence … and last but not least, because the second parameter to `insertRule` specifies the rule _before_ which the new rule should be inserted (so precedence problem on that level again).

Comment: Here’s a modified version of your fiddle where I fixed these issues: http://jsfiddle.net/mUBjc/3/ (I switched out `oninput` for `onchange` as well, because `oninput` fires multiple times while you’re still typing inside the input field, and that would set invalid values most of the time; so I made it fire only once the input loses focus after you changed its value. That of course is still not a validation of whether or not the input value is a valid value for the background property.)

Comment: OK, and this still only worked one time – because using the index `1` again will then of course on second try insert the new rule _before_ the new rule we created before that. That [could be fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/mUBjc/4/) by using `document.styleSheets[1].cssRules.length` as the index, but that will still create a new rule every time a change is made, so they will just keep piling up. To improve on that, one should probably identify the rule that is there to begin with, and _change_ that rule with the updated values, instead of inserting new ones over and over again.

Comment: It seems that I should follow adeneo's advice and yours and simply implement the inline style without so much trouble. Thank you both! :)

Comment: Yes. While dynamically creating/manipulating stylesheets and rules has its use cases – this is rather not one of them. And what you initially quoted from the article is a general rule-of-thumb – but it does not apply to edge cases like the one you are dealing with here.

Comment: @adeneo Please post an answer to this question, so Hermes can accept it an everyone sees that this question has been answered. Thanks

Comment: @adeneo and if you answer, also mention that unlike in CSS, `style.background` is not an existing property in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the answers in the comments, in this case since you are dynamically changing the style depending on a huge number of possible user inputs, modifying the CSS with JavaScript is appropriate. Like the article says, you should just do it as little as possible, but in this case it makes sense.